# dynamic parameters in abstract methods in php

Tags: php, inheritance, abstract

If I have a class,

```
abstract class Parent {
    abstract function foo();
}

class Child extends Parent {
    function foo($param) {
        //stuff
    }
}
```

I get an error because the abstract declaration doesn't have any parameters but the child's implementation of it does. I am making an adapter parent class with abstract functions that, when implemented, could have a variable amount of parameters depending on the context of the child class. Is there any structured way I can overcome this, or do I have to use func_get_args?

Comment: What's the point of abstract class if you have classes that differ from the protocol defined by abstract class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use func_get_args if you want to have variable arguments in your function. Note that func_get_args gets all the arguments passed to a PHP function.

You can however enforce a minimum number of arguments to be passed to the function by including corresponding parameters to them.

For example:
Say that you have a function that you wish to call with at least 1 argument. Then just write the following:

```
function foo($param) {
    //stuff
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
}
```

Now that you have this definition of foo(), you have to at least call it with one argument. You can also choose to pass a variable number of arguments n where n > 1, and receive those arguments through func_get_args(). Keep in mind that $arg_list above will also contain a copy of $param as its first element.

Answer (score 15):

PHP does this to protect polymorphism. Any object of the inherited type should be usable as if they were of the parent type.

Consider the following classes:

```
abstract class Animal {
    abstract function run();
}

class Chicken extends Animal {
    function run() {
        // Clever code that makes a chicken run
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    function run($speed) {
        // Clever code that makes a horse run at a specific speed
    }
}
```

... and the following code:

```
function makeAnimalRun($animal) {
    $animal->run();
}

$someChicken = new Chicken();
$someHorse = new Horse();

makeAnimalRun($someChicken);  // Works fine
makeAnimalRun($someHorse);   // Will fail because Horse->run() requires a $speed
```

`makeAnimalRun` should be able to execute `run` on any instance of `Animal`'s inherited classes, but since `Horse`'s implementation of `run` requires a `$speed` parameter, the `$animal->run()` call in `makeAnimalRun` fails.

Fortunately, there's an easy fix to this. You just need to provide a default value to the parameter in the overridden method.

```
class Horse extends Animal {
    function run($speed = 5) {
        // Clever code that makes that horse run at a specific speed
    }
}
```

Comment: Although your answer helps at one part, it confuses at the other: You can not instantiate an abstract class (like "Animal"), so you will get a fatal error at "$someAnimal = new Animal(); . Of course, you can make the class and method "non-abstract" but then it doesn't fit here.

Comment: @Zaphoid Let's see how chickens run :)